# How to add proxy to Node / Express site?

Tags: json, node.js, proxy, jsonp, express

My site is running on Node and using the Express framework.

My goal is to gather data from the Yahoo Placefinder api. It does not support JSONP, so I need to send my JQuery.getJSON request to my own proxy. My proxy would then send an http request to the Placefinder api, and echo the response.

If I were using php instead of Node, I would just make a new php file that includes a curl request to the placefinder api and echo the response.

But, I am using Node and I'm not sure where to start.

And, I'm using the Express framework.

My Questions are:

1. Where would the proxy fit within the Express framework? The public folder?
2. Where can I find some info on how to code a proxy in Node?
3. Will I need to modify the configuration of my Rackspace cloud (ubuntu) server in order for this to be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add another route to your express app, perhaps at `/api/yahoo/...`.

This view function will then make a call to the Yahoo API, probably using: http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.9/api/http.html#http.request, and then when that request finishes you simple return the result as JSON.

However, keep in mind that your proxy is public and that anyone can make requests through it. I would suggest some basic authorization. A generated value which you provide to the page making the request should work.

Comment: I'm trying to set this up, but get the error "ENOTFOUND, Domain name not found". Here is the related code from my express app.js: http://jsfiddle.net/4J3Wd/ Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Got it working. My mistake was including "http://" in the host value of the .get() options object. Here is the working version: http://jsfiddle.net/4J3Wd/1/

Comment: Can you tell me a little more about how to setup the basic authorization?

Comment: Sure. When you render the page that you plan on making the API request from, generate a code (save it in the user's session), and send it to the page as a js variable. When the page needs to hit your `/api/yahoo` link, include that generated value as a request parameter. Inside your `/api/yahoo` view, check the request parameter against the one in the user's session; if it matches, go through with the request.

Answer (score 13):

2. See [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy). It should be better than implementing your own proxy.
3. Express lets you add middlewares as arguments when you do `express.createServer()`. Or, you can add them afterwards by using `.use(proxy)`.
4. I don't think so.

To give an example (untested code):

```
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy'), express = require('express');
var yahooProxy = httpProxy.createServer(80, 'yahoo.com');
var app = express.createServer();
app.configure(function () {
    app.use('/yahoo', yahooProxy);
});

...
```

Comment: I'm guessing this is the best practices way of doing things... but I can't figure out how to make it work.

Comment: how would you alter the URL in the process?

Comment: @barum-rho for example, i was trying to proxy facebook photos, which are at various hostnames (e.g. `http://a4.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/`).  was trying to figure out a way to pass the entire URL to http-proxy with a URL like `/proxy?src=http://a4.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/...` or `/proxy/http://a4.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/...`

Comment: @AidanFeldman Take a look at the GitHub repository for http-proxy. The second example will do what you want to do with some modification. (https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) Under "Setup a stand-alone proxy server with custom server logic".

Answer (score 4):

Here's another example with 1.0.X that demonstrates header injection.

```
var express = require( 'express' );
var proxy   = require( 'http-proxy' ).createProxyServer;
var app     = express();

app.configure(function() {

  // Inject some request headers here before we proxy...
  app.use( function( req, res, next ) {
    req.headers[ 'x-my-header' ] = 'blah blah';
    next();
  });

  // Proxy based on path...
  app.use( '/stack', proxy({ target: 'http://stackoverflow.com'} ).web );
  app.use( '/yahoo', proxy({ target: 'http://yahoo.com'} ).web );

  app.use( function( req, res ) {
    res.send({ ok: false, message: 'Not much here.' })
  });

}).listen( 3000 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Using http-proxy 1.0 with express:

```
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

var apiProxy = httProxy.createProxyServer();

app.get("/api/*", function(req, res){ 
  apiProxy.web(req, res, { target: 'http://google.com:80' });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays this seems to be the easiest solution to add a proxy to Express:
https://www.npmjs.org/package/proxy-middleware